# how to sync data between unrelated components with different route in angular (rxjs 6)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have problem syncing data between two unrelated components with different route.

if I do this it works:

But I need the two components on a separate route:
localhost:4200/a (componentA)
localhost:4200/b (componentB)

here the code:
service:

```
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
  constructor() {}
  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }
```

componentA:

```
message: string;
  constructor(private ts: StoreService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ts.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }
```

html:

```
{{message}}
```

componentB:

```
message: string;
  constructor(private ts: StoreService) { }
  ngOnInit() {this.ts.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)}

  onChange() {
    this.ts.changeMessage('FROM ACTIVATOR');
  }
```

html:

```
<button type="button" (click)="onChange()">Activate!</button>
{{message}}
```

if I trigger onChange function in componentB it should display 'FROM ACTIVATOR' in both components:

Comment: ...and how are you providing this service, are you making sure it's a singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-h1bqb7)

StoreService should be registered in module providers as below:

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [ AppComponent],
   imports: [ 
      AppRoutingModule, 
      BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule 
   ],
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
   providers: [StoreService] // Injected here
})
export class AppModule { }
```

With Angular7+ we can decorate the service as singleton by following

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StoreService {
}
```

Comment: in your example..you shoud open this on one browser tab..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-h1bqb7?file=app%2Fstore.service.ts and this one on the other tab https://angular-router-basic-example-h1bqb7.stackblitz.io/catalog.

Comment: can you please elaborate? ...or update the stackblitz with the problem you are having

Comment: if you run the application in 2 tabs basically you are running 2 instances of the same app. If you want to share data between multiple apps across one browser then you have to add that data in browser caches like local storage and all. Make sense?

Comment: you should open two tabs the button is in the 1st tab in the home route. 1. https://angular-router-basic-example-h1bqb7.stackblitz.io/home 2. https://angular-router-basic-example-h1bqb7.stackblitz.io/catalog (a common ecommerce scenario wherein customer is opening two tabs..product tab and the shopping cart tab..when customer adds product or increment quantity on the product tab..shopping-cart tab should be updated.

Comment: hot observable to api?

Comment: ok, in that case, you have to save whatever we are changing into some database and on change route, we should always fetch from db and display it. Or if you want to do it in browser level than as i said we have to use browser cache like local storage. I would prefer saving it in backend

Comment: i got you sir. i think you understand my problem. what should i do? everything is saved in the api though..

Comment: do i need hot observable on componentB? what should I need to learn?

Comment: you don't need hot observable. Hot observables are like always emitting values whether you subscribe or not. A good example is browser events which happen across time. All you need to do is call API on route change which has the latest value which is saved on the change button click. That way u can persist data between tabs of browser. It has nothing to do with observables. Hope I helped!
Cheers

Comment: [hot vs cold](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-hot-vs-cold-observables-62d04cf92e03)